# Does Presto Support Hive SerDe?

Tags: presto

I installed Presto and it worked pretty well with CDH4. The problem is that I have a Hive table was defined by with ROW FORMAT SERDE. And Presto seems cannot use it. The error message is as following:

```
Query 20131119_061350_00003_bpk58 failed: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException SerDe myquery.hive.serde.JSONSerDe does not exist)
```

So, is SerDe supported in Presto?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add the SerDe to the `plugin/hive-cdh4` directory inside the installation directory.

Comment: So, the Presto will be able to load it automatically? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, the Hive plugin will automatically access any jars in its directory (note that it has to be the plugin directory and not the main lib directory).

Comment: As of January 2016, I wasn't able to load a Serde this way on EMR Persto-Sandbox (connector is hive-hadoop2 and serde is com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde). I ended up using stock CSV serde

Comment: I tried this out around one year back, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `json-serde-1.1.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar` to your classpath.

Comment: Did you mean the SerDe I wrote? Otherwise, can you explain a little bit how the stock json-serde-1.1.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar is going to understand my customized JSON reading?